# If/else won't exclude the false statement// method?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

The code doesn't work right the program runs both if statements and the total never comes out right. I can't figure out whats wrong. what changes do i need to make for this to work? the directions are below.

The cost to become a member of a fitness center is as follows: (a) the Senior
citizens discount is 30%; (b) if the membership is bought and paid for 12 or
more months in advance, the discount is 15%; or (c) if more than 5 personal
training sessions are purchased, the discount on each session is 20%.
Write a menu driven program that determines the cost of a new membership.
Your program must contain a method that displays the general information about
the fitness center and its charges, a method to get all the necessary information
to determine the membership cost, and a method to determine the membership
cost. Use appropriate parameters to pass information in and out of a method.

what methods should i use?

```
    double grossdiscount1,grossdiscount2,grossdiscount3;
    double grossprice1,grossprice2,grossprice3; 

    //end result of box calculation
    double answerbox1,answerbox2,answerbox3;
    double answerbox1b,answerbox2b,answerbox3b;
    //Jtext inputs
    double box1,box2,box3;

    double discount1 = 0.30 ;
    double discount2 = 0.20 ;
    double discount3 = 0.15 ;
    // prices PT=personal training MT=montly price
    double pricePT =50.00;
    double priceMT =100.00;






    box1 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
    box2 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
    box3 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField3.getText());
// i brought these out of the if statement because the program won't run without
//  them being stated
 answerbox1b=box1*100;
grossdiscount1=(box1*priceMT)*discount3;// the amount saved
grossprice1=(box1*priceMT);
answerbox1=(grossprice1-grossdiscount1);
answerbox2b=(box2*pricePT);
grossdiscount2=(box2*pricePT)*discount2;// the amount saved
grossprice2=(box2*pricePT);
answerbox2=(grossprice2-grossdiscount2);

double total = answerbox1+answerbox2+answerbox1b+answerbox2b;
grossdiscount3=(total*discount3);// the amount saved
grossprice3=total;
answerbox3=(grossprice3-grossdiscount3);




   if(box1<11 )
   {
    answerbox1b=box1*100;
   }
      else if(box1>12)
      {
      grossdiscount1=(box1*priceMT)*discount3;// the amount saved
      grossprice1=(box1*priceMT);
      answerbox1=(grossprice1-grossdiscount1);
      }

   if(box2<5 )
   {
    answerbox2b=(box2*pricePT);
   }
      else if(box2>=5)
      {
      grossdiscount2=(box2*pricePT)*discount2;// the amount saved
      grossprice2=(box2*pricePT);
      answerbox2=(grossprice2-grossdiscount2);
      }

     if(box3==1 )
   {
    grossdiscount3=(total*discount3);// the amount saved
      grossprice3=total;
      answerbox3=(grossprice3-grossdiscount3);
   }
      else if(box3==0);
      {

      }


    jTextField4.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Comment: `else if(box1>12);` - remove the `;`

Comment: The `if` statement does not 'hang up'. It does nothing that could hang up except evaluate a condition, which could block, and then execute zero or one of one or two statements, either of which could block.

Comment: but the programming still doesn't work i have the core but somethings wrong i fell like its running both the if and the else at the same time with the final output thats what i need help with

Comment: @mikeg4523 It is understood that the program doesn't work. What is not understood is your incorrect description of why. You should just describe the symptoms, rather than jumping to an incorrect conclusion about why they occur. Stupid title, too, and indiscriminate tagging.

Answer (score 1):

The else if statements are not written correctly. Remove the ; for a correct flow.

And I also recommend you to check any of the threads related to comparing doubles in Java

Comment: so are you saying its the doubles causing this ?

Comment: The main problem I see is that this statement is not correct else if(box1>12); that means that the next statements between brackets is going to be executed as well. remove the ;. And also, take into account that comparing doubles in Java (and other primitive types) may cause unexpected output

Comment: does that mean i should use floats or the simple else statement

Comment: @mikeg4523 It means you should do what this answer says: remove the `;` in the `else if` statement.

Comment: Yes, remove the ;. Only as a suggestion, check any of the threads for comparing floats

Comment: @Jorge  okay thanks i really appreciate your advice ill remove the extra ";" but will turning my "else if" to "else" stop it form running both conditions. that's the main issue right now. i can change it to a float but won't the same problems happen.

Comment: Compare the double using something like this : new Double(d1).compareTo(new Double(d2)). You can keep your elseif statement

Comment: @mikeg4523 I suggest you stop rationalizing and guessing about this. `;` in the same line as an `if` or `else` is a fundamental error that you need to understand, which prevents it from executing as expected.

Comment: @EJP  i get it the ";" is an error but it takes less then a second to press backspace right now i am trying to figure out why it runs both statements.

Comment: @Jorge do you have a clue why its running both?